# "Import Wizard" option not available in CANoe 17

Tags: can-bus, canoe

I am using free version of CANoe 17 software. I created a candb++ database file. When I try to import it using "Import wizard" option, it is showing me that the option is not available.

[image]

Comment: According to me that option should be available to import data from candb++ file

Comment: What is that "free" version of CANoe called. Not all variants of CANoe allow to modify all aspects of the configuration.

Comment: I think it is the one version where you do not need any licence.